# Microsoft graph API - unauthorized error when subscribing to any calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I went through the classical oAuth flow with permissions `Calendars.ReadWrite` and `offline_access`, which should be enough to create a subscription.

Now I get a list of calendars of the user (via api), and when I try to subscribe to events from any of these calendars with a request like this:

```
POST /v1.0/me/subscriptions HTTP/1.1  Accept: */*  Content-Type: application/json    
{
    "changeType": "created,deleted,updated",
    "notificationURL": "https://...",
    "resource": "/me/calendars/{id}/events",
    "expirationDateTime": "2019-08-15T00:00Z",
    "clientState": "..." 
}
```

(or even `"resource": ,"/me/events"`)

I get the response:

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The error lies within the request url: `POST /v1.0/me/subscriptions` should actually be `POST /v1.0/subscriptions` (without the me)